# How can I have clean error handling whilst testing if my for loop can continue?

Tags: python

I have a list of objects that represent long experiments which are split up in multiple parts: `doThingOne`, `doThingTwo`, etc. I loop over the experiments in a for loop, and if an error occurs, I need to try and fix the conditions for the next experiment. There for I have corresponding `testIfCanContinueOne`, testIfCanContinueTwo`, etc. The only way I can figure out to put these things together gives some very ugly code:

```py
for obj in listOfObjects:
    try:
        foo = doThingOne(obj)
    except Exception as error:
        if testIfCanContinueOne(error):
            continue
        else:
            break
    try:
        result1 = doThingTwo(foo)
    except Exception as error:
        if testIfCanContinueTwo(error):
            continue
        else:
            break
    try:
        result2 = doThingThree(obj, result1)
    except Exception as error:
        if testIfCanContinueThree(error):
            continue
        else:
            break
    SaveResult(result1, result2)
```

The arguments are representative of the interdependencies that exist among the `doThingX` functions.

Is there a way to better structure the code? My main gripe is that the exception handling sits in the way of seeing that the code just does

```py
for obj in listOfObjects:
    foo = doThingOne(obj)
    result1 = doThingTwo(foo)
    result2 = doThingThree(obj, result1)
    SaveResult(result1, result2)
```

Or am I being too nitpicky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it so your `doThingOne`, `doThingTwo` and `doThingThree` raise custom exceptions.
I suppose this might make your code a little more "elegant", though wheather this is practical depends on your exact use-case.

```py
for obj in listOfObjects:
    try:
        foo = doThingOne(obj)
        result1 = doThingTwo(foo)
        result2 = doThingThree(obj, result1)
        SaveResult(result1, result2)

    # catch fixable exeptions, attempt to fix and continue
    except MyFirstException as e:
        print(f"caught fixable exception 1 : '{e}'")
        continue
    except MySecondException as e:
        print(f"caught fixable exception 2 : '{e}'")
        continue

    # can't fix general exceptions, so we break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"failed due to {e.__class__.__name__} : '{e}'")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your try/catch into your functions, and return something according to the fact you can continue or not :

```py
def function1():
  try:
    # Do the things function1 does
  except Exception as e:
    # Check if we can continue
    if can_continue():
      return "letsgo"
    return "cantgoon"
  return theresultofwhatgoesonwithoutexception


if __name__ == '__main__':
  for obj in listOfObjects:
    result1 = function1()
    if "cantgoon" in result1:
      break
    elif "continue" in result1:
      # Take into account result1 is errored and go on
    # If you are still in your loop then all is good
```

The checks are still the same, but this way you make your loop and your `main()` function more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think a really good solution in that case would be to pass those function names as arguments, kind of like this:

```
def wrapper(obj, func, test_func):
    try:
        result = func(obj)
    except Exception as error:
        if test_func(error):
            return True
        else:
            exit()
    return result


def doThingOne(obj):
    # Do stuff
    return obj


def doThingTwo(obj):
    # Do stuff
    return obj


def tEstIfCanContinueOne(error: Exception):
    return True


def tEstIfCanContinueTwo(error: Exception):
    return True


for obj in listOfObjects:
    foo = wrapper(obj, doThingOne, tEstIfCanContinueOne)
    if foo is True:
        continue
    result1 = wrapper(foo, doThingTwo, tEstIfCanContinueTwo)
    if result1 is True:
        continue
```

That way you still have to check if continuing is necessary based on the result of the wrapper, but I think it's much better than before. Hope this helped.